# Java source code display in a browser?

Tags: java, syntax-highlighting, visualization, code-visualization

I have my Java source code in the standard src/ lib/ test/ directory structure for my project. I want to generate a web view of my source code where I can fire up a browser and see syntax-highlighted, line numbered code. I not only want this but I also want the files to be correctly linked (e.g. clicking on a method/class/interface etc name on the webpage view of the code, it would take me "Eclipse-style" to the relevant page). Is there any piece of software that already does this? I know there is tons of syntax highlight js and css out there so that part is easy and thus I am more interested in the linking part.

Comment: "... more interested in the linking part." Highlighting keywords is easy.  Getting cross-references right means simulating what the compiler does in resolving what a name refers to.  That's a lot harder.

Comment: Ira is correct, this could be quite a lot of work. Would producing JavaDocs, with source attached and linked not suffice? Not quite what you described, but maybe close enough?

Comment: @Ira, yes, it is a hard question, else I probably would not be asking :) I would imagine if the bin/ directory is available, we can look at the .class files and the .class files have all the info (they have line numbers too I believe) we need but yes it is hard to do and I don't know any tool that does it.

Comment: @Crollster, no it won't suffice - we have an extremely large code base and sometimes it is faster for engineers to just have a simple web view for what's going on than checkout and update millions of lines of code and grep through it or load it in an IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See our [Java Source Code Browser](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters/JavaBrowser.html).   Combines Java source code browsing with JavaDoc style cross references.   Hyperlinks on identifiers follow Java's scoping rules fully.

Presently operates with Java 1.4, now completing versions for Java 1.5 and up.

EDIT May 2012: Handles Java 1.6 and Java 7

Comment: Awesome - almost exactly what I was looking for. Throw in line numbers and universal code search OpenGrok style and some better syntax highlighting (http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) and support Java6 and I would have exactly what I want!

Comment: no I am in Mountain View but I did go to UT-Austin and yes, I would love to play with the beta. My email is on my profile. Thanks!

Comment: @wrick - your profile says you are in Austin. Time to update it :-}

Comment: The Browser doesn't do searches; it produces pure HTML. You can see a search engine for large scale multilingual system at www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet would be [Cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/).  Out-of-the-box it will generate nice HTML versions of your source.  As a side benefit, it will also generate your code coverage report as well.  ;)

[Maven JXR](http://maven.apache.org/jxr/index.html) is another option as well (if you are using Maven).

Comment: OP said, "thus I am more interested in the cross-linking part".  Does Coberatura produce correct cross-links?

Comment: I just checked the recent version, Cobertura doesn't appear to do cross-links, but Maven JXR does.

Comment: Maven JXR is indeed very close to what I am looking for (http://maven.apache.org/jxr/xref/org/apache/maven/jxr/JavaCodeTransform.html) but it only does Class name hyperlinks. It would be great if it did even method (and variable?) name hyperlinks too. And no, I don't use Maven - as I said I have a very simple project structure with limited external dependencies (I have only 4 jars in my lib/ - Guava, Apache Commons, Log4J and MySQL) so I have not felt the need to use Ant or Maven

Answer (score 0):

[OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) does much of what you are asking for, also allowing for interesting searches.

Comment: Out of curiousity, how does OpenGrok get the cross references correct?  Does it have a full Java name lookup somewhere?

Comment: OpenGrok does not do method/class etc linking